# URL project name part is lost as a result error 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, window.location

I have an issue with reloading a view.
In the controller I use

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
       //some logic adding values in ViewBag parameters
       return View();
    }
```

In the view I have a drop-down list which fires at event onchange. So using the function

```
    function reloadPage(id) {
    var url = "@Url.Action("Index", "ShowGraph")?id="+id;
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

I try to reload the view with new ViewBag values.
The issue now is that when deployed on IIS the path changes.

From
mysite.com/CST/Graph
To 
mysite.com/Graph

The project's name on IIS is lost as a result error 404

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Possible Solutions to try:
 Don't use the `@Url.Action`  try with the hard coded Url 
 check the parameter url on console like: `console.log(url)` , check it is in proper format or not.